# Why Compare function of GitLab say the files are different when they are same?

Tags: git, gitlab, compare, branch, diff

Please go to https://gitlab.com/torrentech/hub.torrentech.org/ and take a look at gitlab-ci.yml on main and dev branches - they are the same.

Now go use Repository>Compare utility and it tells that the files are different showing differences between current and previous version which seem to be stuck somewhere "in limbo".

Don't want to say I found the bug but I really can't explain this? Yes I was tweaking gitlab-ci-yml file in the GitLab interface on main, because I wanted to fast-test if it works, and when it worked out I merge the changes to dev, and the Compare function is broken for me from there on. And then I tried ti Revert that last change - Compare function stills says they are different, but they are the same because I manually edited the dev version to be the same as main, after I reverted.

Gotta admit it's a whole lot of mess in my head now, anybody experienced take a look, probably I'm overseeing something crucial.

Comment: The diff highlights the following differences : on line 46 3 characters are different (highlighted in a darker shade or red/green, main has `%%/` where dev has `|||`), on last line, one version ends without end of line (no `\n` at end) the other one does (since it is hard to view by just printing the lines, most diff tools print an explicit comment "No newline at end of file" when one version does not have this final `\n`). Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yeah I see that, but that is false. gitlab-ci.yml is absolutely the same on both branches, this difference that is displayed is because gitlab-ci.yml was compared to previous version which is in "limbo", you can't find that version in the repository - that's why I'm asking this question. So no, that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to understand why GitLab is behaving like this.

Comment: I noticed that when I choose ... (the option between source and target branches in the Compare interface, GitLab is telling file is the same, and when I choose .. that's where it thinks they are different.

Comment: oh, I see what you mean. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the changes that would be displayed in a merge request, if you wanted to merge `dev` in `main`.

This is the diff between the *merge base of `main` and `dev`* on one side, and `dev` on the other side.

From a cli on your local clone :

- you can get the hash of `git merge-base main dev`
- then inspect `git diff <sha> dev`

or

- run `git diff main...dev` (3 dots, not a typo, documented in the first paragraphs of [`git help diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1))

Comment: Turns out everything was actually ok and regular with my repository, it was just that I was thinking I broke something - you pushed me into right direction with git diff. Anyways, I didn't want to have loads of messy commits, so I did git reset --hard (because I had just a few minor changes after the commit I've reset to), but that was I guess not actually needed for my project - there wasn't anything to fix.